# The point movement on the torus knot

Tags: animation, knots

I would like to ask about the point movement on the torus knot.

```
 rr = 3;
torus[u_, v_] := {(rr + Cos[2 Pi u]) Cos[2 Pi v], (rr + Cos[2 Pi u]) Sin[2 Pi v], Sin[2 Pi u]}
Toro = ParametricPlot3D[torus[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
   Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, MeshStyle -> None];
Knot = ParametricPlot3D[torus[u, 2 u], {u, 0, 1}, Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> False];
```

It's look like:

[image: Tortus and knot image]

And I want to animate the point movement on the torus knot.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curve wound on torus](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115414/curve-wound-on-torus/115445#115445)

Answer (score 4):

```
ListAnimate[
 Table[
  Show[Toro,
   Knot,
   Graphics3D@{Red, Sphere[torus[u, 2 u], .3]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-4.5, 4.5}, {-4.5, 4.5}, {-1.2, 1.2}}],
  {u, 0, 1, .01}]
 ]
```

[image]