# Plot a Satellite Knot

Tags: plotting, knots

I need some help to plot a Satellite or cable knot. For example, see figure A torus knot and a cable knot. (a) The red curve lying on the yellow torus is a (2,3) torus knot. (b) The embedded yellow torus has a (2,3) torus knot at its core. The red curve is a cable knot with Newton pairs (2,3) and (3,2).

(1) https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SatelliteKnot.html

(2) https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.95.053820

[image]

Comment: Might be useful  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115445/72682

Comment: See what you can do with `ParametricPlot3D`, you can `Show` one for the yellow surface and one for the red curve in one plot.  I'll post recrations soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have completely ignored all specifications of the knots (i.e. I don't know what the definition of Newton pair is or exactly what the tuples correspond to).  So, flying by the seat of my pants,

here's my version of the donut

[image: donut]

although personally I like to play with opacities for surface curves

[image: donutgif]

Code for the first version:

```
With[{torus = {(2 + Cos@#2) Cos@#, (2 + Cos@#2) Sin@#, Sin@#2} &}, 
 Show[ParametricPlot3D[
   torus[\[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 
    2 \[Pi]}, MeshStyle -> None], 
  ParametricPlot3D[
   torus[3 \[Theta] + 2, 2 \[Theta]], {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
   PlotStyle -> Darker@Red]]]
```

My knot is less faithful to the given one

[image: knot]

In particular, I think the red curve is parameterized slightly differently.

```
With[{torus = {(2 + Cos@#) Cos@#2, (2 + Cos@#) Sin@#2, Sin@#1} &}, 
 With[{fs = 
  Simplify /@ 
   Last@FrenetSerretSystem[
    torus[3 \[Theta], 2 \[Theta]], \[Theta]]}, 
  Show[ParametricPlot3D[
    torus[3 \[Theta], 
  2 \[Theta]] + .5 Cos[\[Phi]] fs[[2]] + .5 Sin[\[Phi]] fs[[
    3]], {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  MeshStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 50], 
ParametricPlot3D[
 torus[3 \[Theta], 
  2 \[Theta]] + .5 Cos[13 \[Theta]] fs[[2]] + .5 Sin[
   13 \[Theta]] fs[[3]], {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 PlotStyle -> Darker@Red]]]]
```